# How to exchange the role of values and index in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame like the following:

```
work = pd.DataFrame([["Adam","Bob","Charles"],["Bob","Charles","Adam"],["Charles","Adam","Bob"]],index=pd.Index(["Cooking","Cleaning","Grocery"],name="Duty"),columns=pd.Index(["Monday","Wednesday", "Friday"],name="Day"))
```

The table looks like the following:

```
Day        Monday Wednesday   Friday
Duty                                
Cooking      Adam       Bob  Charles
Cleaning      Bob   Charles     Adam
Grocery   Charles      Adam      Bob
```

I would like to exchange the role of the values and the index. So I want a table that looks like this:

```
Day        Monday Wednesday    Friday
Name                                 
Adam      Cooking   Grocery  Cleaning
Bob      Cleaning   Cooking   Grocery
Charles   Grocery  Cleaning   Cooking
```

Is there a simple way of doing this pandas?

**EDIT:**
The rationale behind this output is the following. Suppose there are three roommates live in a house, and they divided the house chores among themselves in a table. In the original DataFrame, by looking up a particular type of work (as index) and a particular day (as column), anyone can see whose duty it is. I want to transform the table such that if I look up the name of the person (as index) and the day of the week (as column), I can immediately see the work this person is supposed to do. In general, there could be `x` person requiring to do `y` types of work, and the list of dates can be arbitrarily long (containing `z` columns). In general `x != y; y != z; z != x`, so there will be missing values in both the original and the transformed DataFrame. The only requirement is that on a particular day, a person performs up to one type of work only (a person can also perform 0 work on any day). This requirement ensures the transformation is 1-to-1.

Comment: I try add solution, but output is different as you. Can you better explain logic of your output?

Comment: @jezrael Thank you very much! I have added more information in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this operation is called "pivoting".

First you need to make the data into a "tall" DataFrame with one row per data point. I did this with a combination of [stacking](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) (which pulls the columns onto a new level in the index) and resetting the index (which makes all levels of the index into their own columns). I also had to call the new column "Name".

```
print work.stack().reset_index(name='Name')
       Duty        Day     Name
0   Cooking     Monday     Adam
1   Cooking  Wednesday      Bob
2   Cooking     Friday  Charles
3  Cleaning     Monday      Bob
4  Cleaning  Wednesday  Charles
5  Cleaning     Friday     Adam
6   Grocery     Monday  Charles
7   Grocery  Wednesday     Adam
8   Grocery     Friday      Bob
```

Now you can [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) it to get the orientation you want.

```
print work.stack().reset_index(name='Name').pivot(
    index='Name', columns='Day', values='Duty')
Day        Friday    Monday Wednesday
Name                                 
Adam     Cleaning   Cooking   Grocery
Bob       Grocery  Cleaning   Cooking
Charles   Cooking   Grocery  Cleaning
```

You can read lots more about [reshaping](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I answered my own question. My current solution is as follows:

```
work_transformed = pd.DataFrame(columns = work.columns)
for name in set(work.values.ravel()):
    name_duty = []
    for date in work:
        name_duty.append(pd.Series(work.index[work[date] == name]).get(0,np.NaN))
    work_transformed.loc[name] = name_duty

work_transformed.sort_index(inplace=True)
work_transformed.index.name="Name"
```

This can produce exactly the same output I want. But I am still wondering if there is any **builtin** way of doing this in pandas?